# Redux call action after other action if condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

How should I implement in redux following logic: There a 2 actions: sync and async. Let say its validate() and save(). When user clicks buttons `validate()` performed and it changes some `isValid` variable in state store. Then if `isValid` save action performed.

Comment: You should perform saveAction when validate happens, and use that to modify both isValid variable and other variables in reducers. No real use in waiting for isValid variable to be set to true.

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli the problem is second action is async (react-thunk), so it can't be just combined with first.

Comment: You can perhaps validate within the async action, instead of a separate validate action. Just an idea.

Comment: Not an answer to the question but a friendly tip: As you're using Redux I'd strongly recommend you taking a look at Redux Sagas ( https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga ). It's a small learning curve but once you got a hang of it you'll be creating async/sync actions in no time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can 'wrap' those functions in 'click handler'.

```
//call it on button click

handleClick = () => {
  if (validate()) {
    //call save function
    save()
  }
}

validate = () => {
  //do something
  //check validness and then
  if (valid) return true 
}
```

Comment: I think validation logic should be in reducer, but not just in clicnk hadler. The point is to implement it in 'redux way'.

Comment: I mean redux actions (http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html) not just JS methods

Comment: I don't think reducer is a good place for this. As for me, I prefer to keep reducer clean from stuff like this and use them just for changing components state. You can create something like utils file and keep there all those functions. But if you don't like this I would recommend you to take a look at redux thunk, it will allow you to return fucntions in action creators, you can specify your logic there.

Comment: I'm already using redux thunk. I can create async actions with it but not "action and then async action" if something. May be I dont get your idea without some code.

Comment: If you have a lot of validation is should definitely be in a method, that method can live in the component or the action file, that depends on how specific to the component the logic is. I don't understand why you need to dispatch a `validate` as a separate action, you should be able to dispatch it in the `save` action then anyone that attempts to use save does not have to know to call validate before saving.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to do what you'd like. However, as a general rule, don't store anything in Redux that can be derived. `isValid` can be derived by running your validation on your field(s). Moreover, I don't think that intermediate state like form field values that are changing belong in Redux. I'd store them in React state until they're considered valid and submitted.

With that out of the way, as Spooner mentioned in a comment, you can call a sync action within a thunk. Or you can access state within the thunk.

Option #1

```
// Action Creator
export default function doSomething(isValid) {
    return (dispatch) => {

        dispatch(setValid(isValid));

        if (isValid) {
            return fetch() //... dispatch on success or failure
        }
    };
}
```

Option #2

```
// Component
dispatch(setValid(isValid));
dispatch(doSomething());

// Action Creator
export default function doSomething() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        const isValid = getState().isValid;

        if (isValid) {
            return fetch() //... dispatch on success or failure
        }
    };
}
```